# callback или EventListeners в Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Какую технику рекомендуете исользовать в *JS*: **EventListeners** или **Callback**-и, и зачем ?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду addEventListener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще есть даже 3 варианта:

- события
- коллбэки
- промисы

Промисы постепенно приходят на смену коллбэкам, как более удобный инструмент. Но, если сравнивать события и коллбэки/промисы, то по сути у них разные области применения. Коллбэки обычно используются в пределах одного компонента, когда программа ожидает выполнения какого-то асинхронного действия. События же применяются для того, чтобы передать данные о действии в какие-то другие компоненты, о существовании которых даже не подозреваешь. Но при этом события избыточны в пределах одного компонента.

Comment: спасибо за ответ ).  а в производительности какая у них разница ?

Comment: Это же асинхронный код, разницы нет.